# dotnet ef migrations: Invalid column name when it has just been added

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core

So apparently, when I add a new model and relations to another existing model, it won't scaffold the migration properly. Even though a migrations file will be created, a chunk load of errors will be shown.

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type 'CounterCore.Data.CounterDbContext'.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.System.IObserver<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.String,System.Object>>.OnNext(KeyValuePair`2 keyValuePair)
         at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener.Write(String name, Object value)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.CoreLoggerExtensions.QueryIterationFailed(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 diagnostics, Type contextType, Exception exception)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery>d__23`1.MoveNext()
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.System.IObserver<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.String,System.Object>>.OnNext(KeyValuePair`2 keyValuePair)
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener.Write(String name, Object value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.CoreLoggerExtensions.QueryIterationFailed(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 diagnostics, Type contextType, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery>d__23`1.MoveNext()
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
      An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type 'CounterCore.Data.CounterDbContext'.
      System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.System.IObserver<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.String,System.Object>>.OnNext(KeyValuePair`2 keyValuePair)
         at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener.Write(String name, Object value)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.CoreLoggerExtensions.QueryIterationFailed(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 diagnostics, Type contextType, Exception exception)
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext()
      --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
         at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
         at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery>d__23`1.MoveNext()
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.System.IObserver<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.String,System.Object>>.OnNext(KeyValuePair`2 keyValuePair)
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener.Write(String name, Object value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.CoreLoggerExtensions.QueryIterationFailed(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 diagnostics, Type contextType, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery>d__23`1.MoveNext()
An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type 'CounterCore.Data.CounterDbContext'.
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.System.IObserver<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<System.String,System.Object>>.OnNext(KeyValuePair`2 keyValuePair)
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticListener.Write(String name, Object value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.CoreLoggerExtensions.QueryIterationFailed(IDiagnosticsLogger`1 diagnostics, Type contextType, Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.<MoveNext>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<ExecuteSingletonAsyncQuery>d__23`1.MoveNext()
```

So here's what I did

User class:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<long>
{
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string ReferralCode { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserReferral> Referrals { get; set; }
}
```

UserReferral Class:

```
public class UserReferral : BaseEntityModel
    {
        public long ReferredUserId { get; set; }

        public string ReferralCode { get; set; }

        public virtual User ReferredUser { get; set; }
    }
```

Within DbContext:
I simply added a new entity for user referral,

```
            builder.Entity<UserReferral>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(ur => ur.ReferredUserId).HasName("UserReferral_PK_Id");

                entity.HasOne(ur => ur.ReferredUser).WithMany().HasForeignKey(ur => ur.ReferredUserId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
            });
```

And a property for the User entity to generate the string randomly on create. And trust me, I tried to fix this 5-10 times over 3 days so I've tried restructuring countless times.

```
entity.HasAlternateKey(u => u.ReferralCode).HasName("User_AK_ReferralCode");
                entity.Property(u => u.ReferralCode).HasDefaultValue(RandomGenerator.GenerateString());
```

DbContext for relations are done as usual, first time facing this issue.